# NuxtJs - how to check useFetch response code?

Tags: nuxt.js, response, httpresponse, nuxtjs3

How can I check response status code when using NuxtJs `useFetch`?

Currently I'm handling response as follows, but I cannot find anywhere how to get the exact response status code, only an error message e.g. `FetchError: 403 Forbidden`.

```js
useFetch(url, options).then(
    (res) => {
        const data = res.data.value;
        const error = res.error.value;

        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            // handle error
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            // handle success
        }
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your template you can, use `error.statusCode`

but in your script you, can use `error.value.statusCode`

check this :

```
<template>
  <div>
    error : {{ error.statusCode }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch("https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountais",
  { pick: ["title"] }
);
console.log(error.value.statusCode);
</script>
```

The `error` object will be empty if you get your request successfully

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well the documentation of nuxt says to do what you are already doing to handle erros [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch/), but I found some links that may help, I'm not a JS expert but I think that this is what you are looking for, [here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/3457) is for getting the status code from the error object, and [here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/4051) I saw the IServerResponse interface as a additional type of an method, and it has the statusCode in it, and last [here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/2122) is another issue with the same problem you was looking for, with answers on how get the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

The following way is better if you want to do something in the script part (set sepcific message etc)

```
await useFetch(URL, {
        onResponse({request, response, options}) {
            // Process the response data
            if (response.status === 200) {
            //your code
            }
        },
        onResponseError({request, response, options}) {
            
            if (response.status === 400) {
              //your code
            } else {
                //your code
            }
            router.push("/")
        },
    });
```